# 'R Cannot be assigned to' error in Roblox Lua

Tags: roblox

I am trying to change the color value of a textlabel. I am doing so using:

```
script.Parent.Parent.toggled2.SurfaceGui.SIGN.TextColor3.R = 0
script.Parent.Parent.toggled2.SurfaceGui.SIGN.TextColor3.G = 255
script.Parent.Parent.toggled2.SurfaceGui.SIGN.TextColor3.B = 0
```

basically it navigates to a button (a part, parent of the script) then to the group its in, then to a part with the text (in this case toggled2) then to the surfacegui inside then the textlabel (which is named SIGN) it then modifies the TextColor3 attribute 3 times at once, adjusting all the R,G,B values.

Why wont it let me alter the value? do i have to do something like `:new()` or `.new()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to assign a value to the `TextColor3` property, you have to pass a `Color3` object :

```
local sign = script.Parent.Parent.toggled2.SurfaceGui.SIGN
sign.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0, 255, 0)
```

Comment: This worked. I also found this after: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/TextBox/TextColor3